# Returning products from useQuery() using react-query

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-query

I have an api that is returning a list of products. I am using the react-query package to fetch the data and then return a map that in turn renders out each product with helper component. Can't seem to get data. I have confirmed that the API is returning data. Problem starts here:

```
return products.map((product) => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} /> 
));
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

This is the React Hook I coded:

```
export default function ProductList() {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useQuery('Products', () => 
    axios('/api/products').then((res) => res.data.products)
  );

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />

  return products.map((product) => (
    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} /> 
  ));
}
```

Here is the helper component:

```
function ProductItem({ product }) {
  const price = formatProductPrice(product);

  return (
    <div className="p-4 md:w-1/3">
      <div className="h-full border-2 border-gray-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
        <Link to={`/${product.id}`}>
          <img 
            className="lg:h-96 md:h-36 w-full object-cover object-center"
            src={product.image}
            alt={product.name}
          />
        </Link>
        <div className="p-6">
          <h2 className="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-500 mb-1">
            {product.category}
          </h2>
          <h1 className="title-font text-lg font-medium text-white mb-3">
            {product.name}
          </h1>
          <p className="leading-relaxed mb-3">{product.description}</p>
          <div className="flex items-center flex-wrap ">
            <Link to={`/${product.id}`} className="text-indigo-400 inline-flex items-center md:mb-2 lg:mb-0">
              See More
              <svg
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                strokeWidth="2"
                className="w-4 h-4 ml-2"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              >
                <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
              </svg>
            </Link>
            <span className="text-gray-500 mr-3 inline-flex items-center lg:ml-auto md:ml-0 ml-auto leading-none text-lg pr-3 py-1 border-gray-800 font-bold">
              {price}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It is most likely something simple, some destructuring error, plurality, or way that I am referencing the data. Grr.

Comment: The message is telling you that `products` is `undefined`, can you use `console.log` to check if its value is what you expect? You should also be doing error handling on your query by checking `if (error) return <SomeFallback />`

Comment: Can't place console.log in the axios call or afterwards due to function scope.  Can't get the values.  I think there is something wrong when casting the data: property as another value, i.e. data: projects, and then referring to it as res.data.projects.  The data is there.

Comment: What is the your response looks like? Should you use `.then((res) => res.data)` instead of `.then((res) => res.data.products)` as data represents the products of array.

Comment: logging can be done like this: `axios('/api/products').then((res) => { console.log(res); return res.data.products })`. It's likely vthat `res.data.products` just doesn't exist and is thus `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try these two suggestions.  I think you are correct in that casting res.data to res.data products is not correct.  Thanks for console.log foo inside axios as well Tk.

Comment: Grr.  Wasn't able to get these to work unfortunately.  This is really puzzling why I can't seem to assign data:products and then reference it.  I used a dummy.json file with this code and it worked.  Maybe it's something with how Strapi is returning the data?

Comment: What is it actually returning? What is `res.data` and what is `res.data.products`? I am confident it's not about `data: products` because that doesn't make any sense, it's just renaming a variable.

Comment: res.data returns the correct data perfect.  res.data.products returned undefined. Puzzling.